# Build / package an electron app in "development" mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, environment-variables, development-environment

I have an **Electron** app (built with Vue.js) that I would like to have both a `production` build as well as a `development` build.

Ideally, I would configure my application to use the `NODE_ENV` environment variable to modify the apps behavior once packaged.

This is primarily for testing auto updates. I want to have a packaged version of the application that points to my dev endpoints, and not to our production endpoints so that we can ensure we aren't rolling out breaking changes to our users.

I can't figure out how to set the NODE_ENV variable as `development` when using electron builder (via the [vue-cli-electron-builder](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/)) to build a packaged app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this simply by passing the `--mode development` flag to the vue-cli.

Hopefully this helps someone!

**Example:**
`vue-cli-service electron:build --mode development`